# Jquery Load function issue in IE6

Tags: javascript, jquery, functional-programming, internet-explorer-6, load

i am using IE6 as a browser and when i call upon a local HTML file as an overlay by using Load function it loads the page but, following things happens
1: shows a loading status bar all the time 
2: All the javascript in the called page(overlay) stopped working.

this is the call code

```
$("#mainoverlay").load("card1.html");
```

Comment: Need more info. The whole script that shows the overlay and the html in the static file will help. Also what loading bar are you talking about. The browser status bar or something else?

Comment: I found out the issue , its the PNG Fix by a HTC file thats causing it.
img, div, input, span, p, .close { behavior: url("iepngfix.htc") }


Any idea how to fix it , or how to fix PNG issue in IE6 , so that i start using alternate and it stopped bugging my Jquery work??

Answer (score 1):

IE6 has known issues with transparent images (IE6 has A LOT of issues). There are numerous javascript fixes for this - but they all work basically the same way with a 1x1 pixel GIF. If you have the ability to go with JPGs or GIFs instead, that would save you a lot of heartache - but I would guess you would have already gone that way if you could have.

One way I've dealt with it in the past is to detect the browser and swap in a non-transparent image (GIF/JPG) if it is IE6. This is approach has many challenges as well and will end up being a significant effort.

The bottom line is that IE6 is just a pain in the rear. You might want to try one of the other IE6 transparent image solutions to try to avoid the conflict, but I wouldn't be optimistic on coming up with a clean execution.

Answer (score 1):

use DD_Belated.png to fix PNGs in IE6 and this may fix this secondary issue:  http://www.dillerdesign.com/experiment/DD_belatedPNG/